# gmailr authentication on headless system

Tags: r, oauth

I'm successfully using [gmailr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmailr/index.html) on Linux Mint. But now I want to move the script that I've developed to a headless Debian server (no X window system). I've registered an "OAuth Client ID" in the Google API manager and downloaded the JSON cred-file. This is the file that I'm currently using on my Linux Mint laptop.

Now I moved the JSON file to the (headless) Debian server and run the script:

```
library(gmailr)
gmail_auth(secret_file = '/local/path/to/auth.json')
```

I get:

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
```

So where do I go from here? Can I simulate a browser in some way? Or is this a dead end?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gmailr_0.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.2.1      magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.3        base64enc_0.1-3
[5] curl_1.2        Rcpp_0.12.7     jsonlite_1.1    httpuv_1.3.3   
[9] openssl_0.9.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer at the gmailr [GitHub](https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/68) page. You need the `.httr-oauth` file in the R working directory... It can becopied from the GUI machine to the headless one.